# Java/Android - Update ArrayList in Anonymous Inner Class

Tags: java, android, class, arraylist, anonymous-class

I am using `Google Cloud Firestore` to store my application's data, and I am trying to retrieve that data and populate an `ArrayList`.

The ArrayList is declared globally and is successfully updated in the anonymous inner class, but when I go to use the `ArrayList` after calling the method containing the anonymous inner class (as well as testing its contents with the below-most Log call), it is showing as empty.

I've been pulling my hair out on this one - any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mCostsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
//Get costs and sales data from Cloud FireStore - updates mCostsArrayList & mSalesArrayList
    getCostTransactions(costsCollectionRef);

//Gets Cloud Firestore costs transactions and puts to mCostsArrayList
private void getCostTransactions(CollectionReference collectionReference){
    collectionReference.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots) {
            if (documentSnapshots.isEmpty()){
                Log.d(TAG, "OnSuccess: LIST EMPTY");
                return;
            } else {
                //Convert the whole Query Snapshot to a list of objects
                //Do not need to fetch each document
                List<BandTransaction> costs = documentSnapshots.toObjects(BandTransaction.class);
                mCostsArrayList.addAll(costs);
                Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess" + mCostsArrayList);
                return;
            }
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error getting data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    Log.d(TAG, "AFTER METHOD" + mCostsArrayList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the line `Log.d(TAG, "AFTER METHOD" + mCostsArrayList);` is called after the `onSuccess(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots)` method? This is a callback method and it can be called much later. Try to call `Log.d(...)` after 2 seconds.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(
            () -> Log.d(TAG, "AFTER METHOD" + mCostsArrayList),
            2000);
```